# Is there a command line tool that will auto pretty-print json?

Tags: json, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I know that tools like 'jq' can let you add a pipe to the command and format it, but you can't use it for situations like displaying real time json logs from a local server. Is there a tool that can achieve that?

Comment: You should be able to use jq with the "--unbuffered" option...

Comment: @Milney I meant situations where the command wouldn't allow the addition of ' | jq' because it can't recognize it.

Comment: Like what command? You should be able to do this with anything....

Comment: You said Json logs? Can you not just tail the file then pipe that to jq?

Comment: @Milney Like running a Node/django/rails server, I don't think you can attach a pipe after the command that runs the server. And while those servers are running, they will output logs which can be in json format.

Comment: Err I'm pretty sure you can certainly redirect their stdout to either a pipe or a file (and then tail the file)... Even just using the > redirect. Why do you think you can't? Have you tried google?

Comment: `journalctl -b -p 4 -o json --no-pager | jq .` works pretty well, so your server should work too with these commands.

Comment: You could also use `-o json-pretty` or `-o json-sse` to format the output and you dont need `| jq .` then.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use a default linux distribution with `systemd` installed, and all services will communicate with `systemd` to make protocol entries.

Back in the days linux created log files only, but they got to big. Then they added `logrotate` to keep it a bit more clean.

A up to date linux distribution uses `systemd` to store protocol entries, which is much better.

To read a protocol you need to find the service you are looking for first.
To list all services connected with `systemd` call ...

```
systemctl list-units | grep service
```

You could use it without `grep` if you really cant use pipes.

Anyway, pick the service you like and call its protocol via `journalctl`. Here are some examples ...

```
journalctl -u ssh.service -p warning -n 30  # (sudo) last 30 warnings and errors SSH created 
journalctl -u apache2.service -p err --no-pager # (sudo) all Apache entries without using the pager (less)
journalctl -k -p err --since today  # (sudo) kernel error messages of today
```

Add the option `-o json` or `-o json-pretty` to it and you will have the output you wanted. You  can also add option `-F` or `--follow` to show most recent journal entries, and continuously print new entries as they are appended to the journal. This way you could make cool backgrounds with `conky` for example.

You can also get the status of your service via `systemctl` ...

```
systemctl status apache2.service    # (sudo) status of Apache
```

---

This way you can pretty print ...

> real time json logs from a local server

like you wanted, and without using `jq` ...

```
admin@suse:~$ journalctl -u apache2.service -p warning -n 1 -o json-pretty --no-pager
{
    "__CURSOR" : "s=65cbb17b253f44c0b800cee690cfb9ee;i=187fd;b=d3effa777ddf4ba9b4f82f126be4439e;m=51cb2bb2d53;t=54b7c4c9ffbeb;x=9fd3b1bc1e50a798",
    "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1490372117134315",
    "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP" : "5620815834451",
    "_BOOT_ID" : "d3effa777ddf4ba9b4f82f126be4439e",
    "_TRANSPORT" : "syslog",
    "_SYSTEMD_SLICE" : "system.slice",
    "_MACHINE_ID" : "dc3b59f36cc34cfa8873c5b530577a2a",
    "_HOSTNAME" : "suse",
    "SYSLOG_FACILITY" : "1",
    "_UID" : "33",
    "_GID" : "33",
    "PRIORITY" : "4",
    "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" : "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/captainlog/search.sh",
    "MESSAGE" : "Request for the specified frontend is not possible. REMOTE_ADDR: xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xxxx",
    "_COMM" : "logger",
    "_CAP_EFFECTIVE" : "0",
    "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP" : "/system.slice/apache2.service",
    "_SYSTEMD_UNIT" : "apache2.service",
    "SYSLOG_PID" : "21314",
    "_PID" : "21314",
    "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1490372117133991"
}
```

[Here is a good guide I found on the internet.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs)